# Accessing webpages that require a password in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, web

So I've figured out how to access a non-secure webpage in java.  However, I do not know how to access a webpage that fist requires you log in on the login page to view.  Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by access?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems similar to this one which points out that not only will you need to send along credentials in your HTTP request (as post or get parameters) but also you may need to consider handling cookies.

[How do I login and download a file from a https web page from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421251/how-do-i-login-and-download-a-file-from-a-https-web-page-from-java)